# Fortran code gives outputs with only certain files

Tags: fortran, mingw, gfortran, mingw-w64

I have 4 .mtx files that I am reading the values from. Two of them run perfectly when read from with no issues and produce the correct outputs into a .DAT file. However, the last 2 are extremely large files; it appears the code correctly reads from the files and runs, but I get no outputs and no errors when reading from these 2...not even the code timer prints the time. Any help is much appreciated! Here is the code:

```
program proj2matrixC40

implicit none
integer,parameter::dp=selected_real_kind(15,307)

! Set Global Variables

real(kind=dp), allocatable::Ax(:,:),A(:,:),Iglobal(:,:)
integer::At(1,3)
integer::nnz,w,n,k,ii,ff,kk
real(kind=dp)::t1,t2
call cpu_time(t1)
open(unit=78,file="e40r5000.mtx",status='old')
read(78,*) At
close(unit=78)
nnz = At(1,3)
n = At(1,1)
k = 40
kk = 35
allocate(Ax(nnz+1,3),A(nnz,3),Iglobal(k,k))
open(unit=61,file="e40r5000.mtx",status='old')
do w=1,nnz+1
   read(61,*) Ax(w,:)
end do
open (unit = 53, file = "proj2matrixC40points.dat")
do ff=1,k
   do ii=1,k
       Iglobal(ii,ff) = (ii/ff)*(ff/ii)
   end do
end do
A(1:nnz,:) = Ax(2:nnz+1,:)
call Arno(A)
call cpu_time(t2)
print '("Time elapsed = ",f10.8," seconds")', (t2 - t1)

contains

subroutine Arno(a)
real(kind=dp), intent(in)::a(:,:)
real(kind=dp),dimension(k,k)::H
real(kind=dp),dimension(k,k+1)::u,q,qconj
real(kind=dp),dimension(k,1)::x0
integer::j,f
call random_number(x0)
q(:,1) = x0(:,1)/norm2(x0(:,1))
do f=1,k
   call spmat(a,q(:,f),u(:,f))
   do j=1,f
      qconj(j,:) = (q(:,j))
      H(j,f) = dot_product(qconj(j,:),u(:,f))
      u(:,f) = u(:,f) - H(j,f)*q(:,j)
   end do
   if (f.lt.k) then
      H(f+1,f) = norm2(u(:,f))
      if (H(f+1,f)==0) then
         print *, "Matrix is reducible"
         stop
      end if
      q(:,f+1) = u(:,f)/H(f+1,f)
   end if
   if (f==k) then
      call qrit(H)
   end if
end do
end subroutine

! QR Iteration with Shifts Subroutine

subroutine qrit(a)
real(kind=dp), intent(in)::a(:,:)
real(kind=dp)::sigmak
real(kind=dp),dimension(kk,k)::dia
real(kind=dp),dimension(k,k)::Qfinal,Rfinal,HH
real(kind=dp),dimension(k,k,kk)::H0,needQR
integer::v,z
HH = a
   H0(:,:,1) = HH
   do v=1,kk
      sigmak = H0(k,k,v)
      if (v-1==0) then
          needQR(:,:,v) = HH - sigmak*Iglobal
      else
          needQR(:,:,v) = H0(:,:,v-1) - sigmak*Iglobal
      end if
      call givens2(needQR(:,:,v),Rfinal,Qfinal)
      H0(:,:,v) = matmul(Rfinal,Qfinal) + sigmak*Iglobal
      do z = 1,k
         dia(v,z) = H0(z,z,v)
         write(53,*) v," ", dia(v,z) ! Write values to .DAT file
      end do
   end do
end subroutine

! Sparse Matrix Vector Multiplication Subroutine

subroutine spmat(a,b,c)
real(kind=dp), intent(in)::a(:,:)
real(kind=dp), intent(in), dimension(k,1)::b
real(kind=dp), intent(out), dimension(k,1)::c
integer::m,rowi,columni
real(kind=dp), dimension(k,1)::x,y
x = b
y(:,1) = 0
do m = 1,nnz
   rowi = a(m,1)
   columni = a(m,2)
   y(rowi,1) = y(rowi,1) + a(m,3)*x(columni,1)
end do
c(:,1) = y(:,1)
end subroutine

! QR Factorization Givens Rotations Subroutine

subroutine givens2(a,Rfinal,Qfinal)
real(kind=dp), intent(in)::a(:,:)
real(kind=dp), dimension(k,k,(k*k))::G,QQ
real(kind=dp), dimension(k,k), intent(out)::Rfinal,Qfinal
real(kind=dp), dimension(k,k)::I2,y,aa
real(kind=dp), dimension(1,k)::ek1,ek2
real(kind=dp)::c,s
integer::kt,m,nn,j,i,l,p
m = size(a,1)
nn = size(a,2)
aa = a
i = 1
do kt=1,nn-1
   do j=m,kt+1,-1
      if (aa(j,kt).eq.0) then
          continue
      else
         ek1(1,:) = 0
         ek2(1,:) = 0
         do p=1,m
            do l=1,m
               I2(l,p) = (l/p)*(p/l)
            end do
         end do
         c = aa(kt,kt)/sqrt(aa(kt,kt)**2 + aa(j,kt)**2)
         s = aa(j,kt)/sqrt(aa(kt,kt)**2 + aa(j,kt)**2)
         ek1(1,kt) = c
         ek1(1,j) = s
         ek2(1,kt) = -s
         ek2(1,j) = c
         I2(kt,:) = ek1(1,:)
         I2(j,:) = ek2(1,:)    
         G(:,:,i) = I2
         if (i.eq.1) then
            QQ(:,:,i) = G(:,:,i)
         else 
            QQ(:,:,i) = matmul(G(:,:,i),QQ(:,:,i-1))
         end if
         y = matmul(G(:,:,i),aa)
         aa = y
         if (kt.eq.nn-1) then
            if (j.eq.kt+1) then
               Qfinal = transpose(QQ(:,:,i))
               Rfinal = aa
            end if
         end if
         i = i + 1
      end if
   end do
end do
end subroutine

end program proj2matrixC40
```

A couple notes. The line which I put asterisks around (for this question) `call mat_print('H',H)` can't be deleted otherwise I get the wrong answers (this is strange...thoughts?). Also so your computer won't freeze opening the big files, their names are 'e40r5000.mtx' and 's3dkt3m2.mtx' (these are the two I have issues with). I am using gfortran version 8.1.0

Here is the link to the files

https://1drv.ms/f/s!AjG0dE43DVddaJfY62ABE8Yq3CI

Comment: He's not joking when he says that the files are very large -- about 500k lines.

Comment: But there are so many strange decisions in the code. Some examples: in subroutine `qrit` there's a nested loop, with the body only being executed if the two iterators are identical. In `spmat` there is a `do l=1, 1`

Answer (score 4):

When you need to add a call to a subroutine that shouldn't actually change anything in order to get things working, you probably have a memory corruption. This happens most often when you access arrays outside of their boundaries.

I have compiled it with some run time checks:

```
gfortran -o p2m -g -O0 -fbacktrace -fcheck=all -Wall proj2mat.f90
```

And it's already giving me some issues:

- It's warning me about implicit type conversions. That shouldn't be too much of an issue if you trust your data.
- In line 46 you have an array length mismatch (`x0(:, 1)` has length 40, `q(:,1)` is 41)
- Similarly on line 108 (`x=b`) `x` is really large, but `b` is only 41 long.

I have stopped now, but I implore you to go through your code and clean it up. Use the compiler options above which will let you know when and where there is an array bound violation.

Comment: Fixed issues running with `gfortran -g -O0 -fbacktrace -fcheck=all proj2matrixC40.f08` and this fixed the issue with the call statement. First two matrices still run great as normal. However, now I am getting the error statement "Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference." when reading from the two large files but there are no accesses to arrays that are prohibited (I shouldve gotten an error reading from the first two!). I even tried `gfortran -fmax-array-constructor=1000000 -fmax-stack-var-size=1000000 proj2matrixC40.f08` and that didn't work either

Comment: The changed the code in the question to now the updated one

Comment: Figured it out:) Thanks for your help!